# synchronized method instead of synchronized statement in java

Tags: java, synchronization

I have a method with a synchronization statement on an "non-this" object

```
class Some_Class { 
  public A s = new A();
  public void method_A() { 
    synchronized(s) { 
      ....
    } 
  }
}
```

Can I instead extend class A and synchronize as follows:

```
class B extends A {  
  public A a;
  public B(A a) {  
    this.a = a; 
  }  
  public synchronized void some_m() {  
    ...  
  }  
}   
class Some_Class {  
  public A s = new A();
  public void method_A() {
    B b = new B(s);
    b.some_m();
  }  
}
```

Are these two synchronizations equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

No, they're not equivalent. This method here:

```
public synchronized void some_m() {  
  ...  
}
```

Does the same as this one:

```
public void some_m() {  
    synchronized(this) {
        ...  
    }
}
```

Or in other words

1. Your first code option synchronises on an instance of `A` in `Some_Class` (a class member, visible to everyone).
2. Your second code option synchronises on the instance of `B` within `Some_Class.method_A()` (a local variable, invisible to the outside of that method)

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not equivalent. In second case you actually don't have synchronization at all. Because `some_m` method synchronized on instance of `B`. So you create local instance of B and call method on it. This method is synchronized only on this local instance of B and other threads don't care about it and can do whatever they want with `s` because it's not synchronized.
Can you describe what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Lukas Eder. Thanks for all answers. I am trying to avoid synchronization on the instance of class A in a synchronization statement (like in method_A()) without changing neither the source nor the byte code of A.

Comment: @stephan why do you try that? Something wrong with synchronization on the instance of `A`?

Comment: No, there is nothing wrong with synchronization on the instance of A.

Comment: No, there is nothing wrong with synchronization on the instance of A. I just want to avoid try-catch blocks in the byte code of the synchronization statement. Now I think that I must change the class variable of A to B, and then this approach will be right.

Comment: @stephan Yes, you can try this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. I will now try.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronized block synchronizes the whole object while synchronized method synchronizes just that method. In the second case, some thread can still access other non-synchronized methods of the object.

Comment: It synchronizes on object, not method. So if there is other `synchronized` methods other thread won't be able to access them.

Comment: I want to say that if there is a synchronized method and a normal method, the normal method can still be accessed by another thread. Isn't that right?

Comment: yes, it's right.  I just didn't like "synchronize just that method" part.